# How to reload UITableView inserted items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm looking on how to load date for an UITableView (inserted items only).

I'm using a library called [UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll][1]

[1]: https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll for infinite scroll, and when I'm adding new items I want only the new items to be loaded.

When I call `tableView.reloadData()` it's loading all the TableView

Here is my full code :

```
 tableView.infiniteScrollIndicatorStyle = .Gray

        tableView.addInfiniteScrollWithHandler { (scrollView) -> Void in

            self.loaddata(10, skip: self.posts.count)


        }

func loaddata(limit:Int, skip:Int) {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Feed")
        query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.phones)
        query.limit = limit
        query.skip = skip
        query.includeKey("from")
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects {
                    if objects.isEmpty {

                    }
                    else {
                        print(objects.count)
                        for object in objects {
                            let Date = object.createdAt
                            let post = Post(time: Date!)
                            let Type = object.objectForKey("type") as? String

                            post.DoILike = true
                            post.Post_message = object.objectForKey("Text") as? String
                            post.comments = object.objectForKey("commentaires") as? Int
                            post.likes = object.objectForKey("likes") as? Int

                            self.posts.append(post)

                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.finishInfiniteScroll()
                    }

                }

            } else {


            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something like

```
let indexPaths = ... //indexes of added rows
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```